# In ischoric process, $dU=dQ$. Does it mean Cp=Cv?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics

Simply,

$dU=nC_vdT$

$dQ=nC_pdT$

Does this mean that $C_p=C_v$ for an isochoric process?

Comment: What makes you think that $dQ=nC_pdT$ for an isochoric process?

Comment: I solved a question in my textbook for an isobaric process where both these equations I have mentioned were used so I figured it is the case for every thermodynamic process

Comment: Besides in our books writers just differentiate the equations without stating whether we can apply the formula for certain situation like this or not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notation: $\delta X$ represents a small change in $X$ that is not an exact differential. $dX$ represents and exact differential. $dX_Y$ etc represent a change in $X$ during a process for which $Y$ is fixed. E.g. $\delta Q_p$ means the small change in heat during an isobaric process, for which we know $\delta Q$ is not an exact differential.

We define $C = \frac{\delta Q}{dT}$ as the heat capacity for a process in which the temperature changed by the infinitesimal (exact differential) $dT$ and the heat transferred is $\delta Q$. If in a process we keep the quantity $X$ constant, we write $C_X = \frac{\delta Q_X}{dT}$ to remind us what process this heat capacity is for.

Now to your questions:

Your first equation is: 
$dU = C_V dT$

This is always true if the process happens at constant volume so that no work happens. As then $dU = \delta Q = C_V dT$. However, since if volume is constant $dU = \delta Q$ is not true, we can't in general conclude $dU = C_XdT$ for a process where $X$ is held constant. This is a common source of confusion.

In fact, for an ideal gas one can show that $dU = C_VdT$ for any process.

Your second equation is:
$\delta Q = C_p dT$

This is just the definition of $C_X$ for a process where $X=p$ is constant. In this instance we would have $dU = \delta Q + \delta W = C_p dT + \delta W$. The presence of the work term $\delta W$ prevents you from equating $C_V$ and $C_p$.

Bonus: In fact, one can show (for an ideal gas) that we have:

$dU = \delta Q_p + \delta W_p = C_v dT_p$

$\implies C_p dT_p -pdV_p = C_v dT_p$

$\therefore C_p-C_V = p\left( \frac{\partial V}{\partial T}\right)_p = nR$

Where we have used the fact it is an ideal gas to write that $dU = C_v dT$ as well as the ideal gas law to evaluate the partial derivative in the last line.

Answer (score 1):

No.

Specific heats do not depend on the process and are constants(for a given material at a specific Temperature).

$C_v$ is specific heat for constant volume and $C_p$ is for constant pressure. You apply them according to these conditions. In Isochoric process only $C_v$ is relevant since it is constant volume process. However if you consider Isobaric process(constant pressure) then only $C_p$ is relevant.

In fact there is a relation between the two specific heats -$$C_p - C_v = R$$.

Comment: Regarding the equation:  Is that ALWAYS true, or only under certain circumstances?

Comment: It's valid for an ideal gas.

Comment: @22134484:  The more general relationship (true for any substance) is $C_p - C_v = TV \beta^2/\kappa_T$, where $\beta$ is the thermal expansion coefficient and $\kappa_T$ is the isothermal compressibility.